# openMP only on inner loop not working

Tags: c, openmp

This is an update to my original question with a working code and runtimes included.

I have a simple code that does a 2D random walk with multiple walkers over a number of steps. I'm trying to parallelize the walkers into group on each thread with openMP only on the inner loop.

Here is the code. It outputs step number vs root mean square displacement (RMSD). The plot of Step vs RMSD should follow a power law with index around 0.5 as a check on the results (which it does).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){

  // define variables
  int    i,j;
  double msd,xij,yij,randm;

  // inputs
  // ----------------------
  // set size
  int walkers = 2000;
  int steps   = 50000;
  // ----------------------

  // allocate arrays
  double *xpos = malloc(walkers*sizeof(double));
  double *ypos = malloc(walkers*sizeof(double));
  double *thet = malloc(walkers*steps*sizeof(double));
  int    *step = malloc(steps*sizeof(int));
  double *rmsd = malloc(steps*sizeof(double));

  // initialize
  double dr = 0.2;
  double pi = 4.0*atan(1.0);
  for(i=0; i<walkers; i++){
    xpos[i] = 0.0;
    ypos[i] = 0.0;
  }

  // generate random angles
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(i=0; i<steps; i++){
    for(j=0; j<walkers; j++){
      randm = rand();
      randm = (randm/RAND_MAX)*2.0*pi;
      thet[i*walkers+j] = randm;
    }
  }

  // random walk
  #pragma omp parallel private(i,j,xij,yij)
  for(i=0; i<steps; i++){
    msd = 0.0;
    #pragma omp barrier
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:msd)
    for(j=0; j<walkers; j++){
      xpos[j] += dr*cos(thet[i*walkers+j]);
      ypos[j] += dr*sin(thet[i*walkers+j]);
      xij = xpos[j];
      yij = ypos[j];
      // get displacement
      msd += xij*xij + yij*yij;
    }
    // store values to array
    #pragma omp single
    step[i] = i+1;
    #pragma omp single
    rmsd[i] = sqrt(msd/walkers);
  }

  // write output to file
  FILE *f = fopen("random_walk_c_omp.txt","w");
  for(i=0; i<steps; i++){
    fprintf(f,"%i  %f\n",step[i],rmsd[i]);
  }
  fclose(f);

  // free arrays
  free(xpos);
  free(ypos);
  free(thet);
  free(step);
  free(rmsd);

}
```

Here are the runtimes.

Serial version compiled without OpenMP:

```
gcc-5 random_walk_c_omp.c -o random_walk_c_omp -O3 -Wall
time ./random_walk_c_omp
2.55 real         2.36 user         0.18 sys
```

OpenMP version with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`:

```
gcc-5 random_walk_c_omp.c -o random_walk_c_omp -O3 -Wall -fopenmp
time ./random_walk_c_omp
2.81 real         2.62 user         0.17 sys
```

OpenMP version with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4`:

```
gcc-5 random_walk_c_omp.c -o random_walk_c_omp -O3 -Wall -fopenmp
time ./random_walk_c_omp
4.36 real         3.42 user         3.80 sys
```

I'm no expert with C so feel free to throw stones here, but is there something wrong with this OpenMP implementation that would explain why it's slower than the serial version? My guess is because of the little work load of the inner loop compared to the many iterations of the outer loop.

Comment: Once you put an `omp parallel` pragma, all threads start to execute its body; in your case, all threads execute `steps` iterations, where `msd` is a shared variable. Is that intended? Didn't you mean to use only `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:msd)` ?

Comment: also, `k` is accessed/modified from multiple threads

Comment: My intent was to put the `#pragma omp parallel` statement before the outer loop so that all threads are initialized once, with the `#pragma omp for reduction(+:msd)` only on the inner loop so that the walkers are run in parallel for each of `steps`. My thought is that `msd` can't be declared private if its used in a `reduction(+:msd)` statement.

Comment: currently, all threads execute `for(i=0; i<steps; i++)`, each one starts a new for loop, and they mutually overwrite the value of `i`

Comment: Is there a correct way to parallelize only the inner loop then without the overhead of starting up new threads on each iteration of the outer loop? The code produces correct results when I only have  `#pragma omp parallel for private(j,xij,yij) reduction(+:msd)` before the inner loop, but it runs slower than the serial version and worse with more threads. I assume this is due to the overhead of forking new threads on every iteration of the outer loop. How can this be avoided?

Comment: how big is `walkers` ?

Comment: `walkers` and `steps` are both at least 1000

Comment: did you try `schedule(static, 16)` ?

Comment: doesn't seem to help